# Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Dedekind Cuts, Multiplicative Inverse

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

At the top of the page 20 of Rudin's book ''Principles of Mathematical Analysis'' he writes:
''The proofs (of the multiplication axioms) are so similar to the ones given in detail in Step 4 (proof of the addition axioms) that we omit them''. I tried to prove them but I got stuck in the proof of 
\begin{equation}\alpha \cdot {\alpha }^{-1}=1^*\end{equation}
 where $\alpha$ is positive cut and ${\alpha }^{-1}=\mathbb{Q}_{-}\bigcup\left\{0\right\}\bigcup\left\{t\in \mathbb{Q}:0<t<r\text{ for some }r\in \mathbb{Q}:\frac{1}{r}\notin \alpha\right\}$ is the candidate for the multiplicative inverse of $\alpha$. I have already proved that ${\alpha }^{-1}$ is a cut and $\alpha \cdot {\alpha }^{-1}\le 1^*$.

My question is how do we prove the opposite direction **similarly to the proof Rudin gives for** $\alpha +(-\alpha) \le 0^*$. A proof completely different to that one can be found here: [Dedekind cut multiplicative inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/157167/dedekind-cut-multiplicative-inverse)

Here is what I have tried thus far:

Let $p\in 1^*$. If $p\le 0$ then obviously $p\in \alpha\cdot \alpha^{-1}$.

Suppose $0<p<1$ and $q=q(p)\in \mathbb{Q}_{+}$. By the Archimedean Property of Rational numbers
\begin{equation}\exists n\in \mathbb{N}:nq\in \alpha\text{ and }(n+1)q\notin \alpha\end{equation} 
We must find a $u \in \alpha^{-1}$ such as that $p=(nq)\cdot u$ or equivalenty, $u=\frac{p}{nq}$

In order for $u \in \alpha^{-1}$ we must have that $0<u<r$ and $\frac{1}{r}\notin \alpha$ for some rational $r$. The only reasonable choice for $r$ would be $\frac{1}{(n+1)q}$. But then,
\begin{equation}u<r\Leftrightarrow \frac{p}{nq}<\frac{1}{(n+1)q}\Leftrightarrow p<\frac{n}{n+1}\end{equation} which may not be true for some values of $n$ (like $0$). Where can we derive a restriction for these values of $n$?

EDIT: Found another proof here: http://mypage.iu.edu/~sgautam/m413.33418.11f/Dedekind.pdf
STill nothing similar to Rudin's...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156853/multiplication-inverse-for-dedekind-cut

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $p\in 1^*$ with $0 < p < 1$. There exists an $n\in \mathbb N$ such that
$$
p < 1 - \frac 1 {m + 1} = \frac m {m + 1} \tag{1}
$$
for each $m\in \mathbb N$, $m \geq n$.

Let $r\in \alpha, r >0$ and $0 < q < r/n$. There exists an $m$ such that $m q\in \alpha$ and $(m + 1)q\notin \alpha$. Evidently we have $m \geq n$.

Inequality (1) implies
$$
\frac p {mq} < \frac m {m + 1}\cdot \frac 1 {mq} = \frac 1 {(m + 1) q}
$$
so $\frac p {mq} \in \alpha^{-1}$ and 
$$
p = (mq)\cdot \frac p {mq}.
$$

Comment: Very very nice proof! Not exactly what I was looking for but still, this is fantastic! You made my day! Note: In the beggining you must let $0<p<1$, but that won't affect proof at all as the other case is obvious

Comment: I assumed $0 < p < 1$, because that was the only case you had difficulties with. Anyway, now, I explicitly mentioned that condition.

Comment: Sorry to reopen a question decided two years ago, but precisely why is it evident that $m \geq n$?  Otherwise I agree completely...

Comment: Since $p < 1$, there exists an integer $n$ great enough to satisfy $p < 1 - (n + 1)^{-1}$. Then for each $m$ greater than $n$ inequality (1) holds.

Comment: @User12345 $0<q<r/n$ and $mq<rm/n$ then $(m+1)q<r(m+1)/n$. If $m<n$ then $m=n-k$ for some $k\geq 1$ hence $(m+1)/n = (n-k+1)/n = 1+(1-k)/n\leq 1$. This implies $(m+1)q<r(m+1)/n\leq r$, then $(m+1)q\in\alpha$, which is contradictory.

Comment: I just came across with this response from 2 years ago, and I'm still confused as to why $\frac {p}{mq} < \frac {m}{m + 1}\cdot \frac {1}{mq} = \frac {1}{(m + 1) q}$ implies that $\frac {p}{mq}\in\alpha^{-1}$?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT, February 16th, 2022:** *I never intended this to be a perfect exposition — my aim was simply to show that Rudin's proof for addition could be translated analogously to multiplication. But now that I read over what I wrote, I see there are little inaccuracies everywhere, so I feel compelled to try to fix them. Deviations from Rudin are in brackets.  A more significant gap in logic, pointed out by commenter Gary, is addressed below.*

I think we can reproduce Rudin's proof completely analogously. I will try to copy Rudin's exposition nearly symbol by symbol.

Fix $\alpha \in \mathbb R^+$. Let $\beta$ be the union of $(-\infty,0]$ with $\beta^+$, the set of all $p>0$ with the following property: *There exists $r>1$ such that $(1/p)/r \notin \alpha$.*

We show that $\beta \in \mathbb R^+$ and $\alpha\beta = 1^*$.

If $s \notin \alpha$ [so that $s > 0$] and $p=(1/s)/2$, then $(1/p)/2=s \notin \alpha$, hence $p \in \beta$. So $\beta^+$ is not empty [because $p > 0$]. If $0 < q \in \alpha$ [which exists because $0^* < \alpha$], then $1/q \notin \beta$. So $\beta \ne \mathbb Q$. Hence $\beta$ satisfies (I).

Pick $0 < p \in \beta$ [which exists because $\beta^+$ is nonempty], and pick $r > 1$, so that $(1/p)/r \notin \alpha$. If $0 < q < p$, then $0 < (1/p)/r < (1/q)/r$, hence $(1/q)/r \notin \alpha$. Thus $q \in \beta$, and (II) holds.

[For the proof of (III), Rudin uses the expression '$r/2$', which in multiplicative language would be '$\sqrt r$', which may not be rational. We can do just as well with rational $j,k$ satisfying $1<j,k$ and $jk = r$. For example, we can choose $j = {1+r\over 2}$ and $k = r/j = {2r \over 1+r}$, which are both greater than $1$ if $r$ is.]

Put $t = pj$. Then $t > p$, and $(1/t)/k = (1/p)/r \notin\alpha$, so that $t \in \beta$. Hence $\beta$ satisfies (III).

We have proved that $\beta \in \mathbb R$ [and, since $\beta^+$ is nonempty, that $\beta \in \mathbb R^+$].

If $0 < r \in \alpha$ and $0 < s \in \beta$, then $1/s \notin \alpha$, hence $r < 1/s$, $rs < 1$. Thus $\alpha\beta \subseteq 1^*$.

To prove the opposite inclusion, pick $v \in 1^*$, $v > 0$. [Once again, we would like to follow Rudin and set $w = 1/\sqrt v$, but $\sqrt v$ may not be rational. It suffices to take rational $j,k$ satisfying $0<j,k<1$ and $jk = v$. For example, we can choose $j = {v+1\over 2}$ and $k = v/j = {2v \over v+1}$, which are both less than $1$ if $v$ is.]

Put $w = 1/j$. Then $w > 1$, and there is a nonnegative integer $n$ such that $w^n \in \alpha$ but $w^{n+1} \notin \alpha$. **(See Comment below.)** [This follows from $w^n = ((w-1)+1)^n > n(w-1)$ by binomial expansion, then using the archimedean property of $\mathbb Q$, since $w-1>0$.] Put $p = k/w^{n+1}$. Then $p \in \beta$, since $(1/p)/(1/k) \notin \alpha$, and $$v = w^np \in \alpha\beta.$$ Thus $1^* \subseteq \alpha\beta$.

[**Comment:** This argument does not work if $w^0 = 1$ is not in $\alpha$, for in that case there is no nonnegative integer $n$ with the required property. However, in that case we can simply switch the roles of $\alpha$ and $\beta$: Indeed, if $1 \notin \alpha$, then $\alpha < 1^*$, from which it follows that $\beta > 1^*$. And there is a symmetry between $\alpha$ and $\beta$, in that $\alpha$ is the union of $(-\infty,0]$ with $\alpha^+$, the set of all $p > 0$ such that there exists $r>1$ which satisfies $(1/p)/r \notin \beta$. Hence we can switch $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in the preceding paragraph and draw the same conclusion, as claimed.]

We conclude that $\alpha\beta = 1^*$.

Comment: "This follows from $w^n=((w-1)+1)^n>n(w-1)$ by binomial expansion..."   Binomial expansion with negative powers would seem to rely on calculus material that Rudin cannot develop without first developing the real numbers...

Comment: I don’t think I intended to use this fact with negative values of $n$. It’s been a long time since I wrote this and don’t remember the details but near as I can tell the claim is not true if $\alpha<1^\ast$. But then $\beta>1^\ast$, and one can check that $\alpha$ has the same property with respect to $\beta$ that $\beta$ has with respect to $\alpha$, so there is complete symmetry and the argument can go through with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ switched. 

Or not! You tell me! :P

Comment: My guess is the claim is true for $\alpha{}<1^*$ if we allow negative $n$ but I can't even approach that case without developing derivatives first. I believe you are correct about symmetry. Your answer helped me a lot. Would you consider modifying your answer to restrict yourself to $n\in{}\mathbb{N}$ and incorporate the symmetry argument?

Comment: @Gary, done, with several other inaccuracies attended to.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. For any student who will come across this and will wonder about why $\alpha{}<1^{*}\implies{}1^{*}<\beta{}\,\,$: $\,\,\alpha{}<1^{*}\implies{}\exists{}q(q\in{}\mathbb{Q}^+\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,q<1\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,q\not\in{}\alpha{})$. Define $q':=\frac{1+q}{2}$ so $q<q'<1$ and $q'\not\in{}\alpha{}$ and $\frac{1}{q'}>1$. Set $r:=\frac{1+q}{2q}$ and note $r>1$. Then $\frac{q'}{r}\not\in{}\alpha{}$ shows $\frac{1}{q'}\in{}\beta{}$, requiring $\beta{}>1^{*}$.

Comment: Yes, and of course you also have to prove the symmetry between $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Comment: Yes, there are many details one could fill in — the same is true of Rudin's original proof. But I'm not sure the OP's question was about filling in the details, it was about trying to understand what Rudin had in mind.

Comment: Existence of $n$: $k\in{}\mathbb{N}\,\cup\,\{0\}\implies{}w^k=((w-1)+1)^k=\sum_{i=0}^k\binom{k}{i}(w-1)^i1^{k-i}$ $=1+k(w-1)+\ldots{}+k(w-1)^{k-1}+(w-1)^k>k(w-1)$. By the A.P. of $\mathbb{Q}$, I can choose $k$ such that $k(w-1)>q$ for $q\in{}\alpha{}$. Then $q<k(w-1)<w^k$ thus $w^k\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\alpha{}$. Also $1=w^0\in{}\alpha{}$. Define $S:=\{i|i\in{}\mathbb{N}\,\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\,w^i\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\alpha{}\}$. The above shows $S\neq{}\varnothing{}$. By WOP, $S$ has a min element $m$. Set $n=m-1$. Then $w^n\in{}\alpha{}$ and $w^{n+1}\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\alpha{}$.

Comment: Symmetry claim: $\alpha{}=S$, where $S=\{q|q\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\wedge{}\,\,q\leq{}p\,\,\wedge{}\,\,p\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\exists{}r(r\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\wedge{}\,\,r>1\,\,\wedge{}\,\,\frac{1}{pr}\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\beta{})\}$. Proof: $(\subset{})$: Choose $q\in{}\alpha{},\,\,q\neq{}0$. $q\in{}\alpha{}\implies{}\exists{}q'(q'\in{}\alpha{}\,\,\wedge{}\,\,q<q')$. Set $r:=\frac{q'}{q}$ and note that $r>1$. Then $\frac{1}{qr}=\frac{1}{q'}\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\beta{}$ shows that $q\in{}S$.

Comment: Symmetry claim proof (part two): $(\supset{}):$ $q\in{}S\implies{}q\leq{}p$ for $p\in{}\mathbb{Q}$ satisfying $\frac{1}{pr}\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\beta{}$ for some $r\in{}\mathbb{Q},\,\,r>1$. $\frac{1}{pr}\in{}\mathbb{Q}\setminus{}\beta{}\implies{}\forall{}r'(r'\in{}\mathbb{Q}\,\,\wedge{}\,\,r'>1\implies{}\frac{pr}{r'}\in{}\alpha{})$. Take $r':=r$ to show that $p\in{}\alpha{}$ and therefore $q\in{}\alpha{}$.