# Prove that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ by showing that $x\cdot x=2$ where $x=A|B$ is the Dedekind Cut in $\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

Problem statement:

Prove that $\sqrt{2} \in \mathbb{R}$ by showing that $x\cdot x=2$ where $x=A|B$ is the Dedekind Cut in $\mathbb{Q}$ where $A=\{r\in\mathbb{Q}:r\leq0\text{ or } r^2 < 2\}$.

---

Attempt:

$x\cdot x = E|F  = \{r\in\mathbb{Q}:r\leq0 \text{ or } \exists a,a' \in A \text{ such that } a\cdot a' = r\}|\text{ rest of }\mathbb{Q}$

### Establish that $E\subset2^*$

Two cases to consider:

1. $a<a'\implies a\cdot a'<a'\cdot a'<2$
2. $a'\leq a\implies a\cdot a'\leq a\cdot a<2$

In both cases, $a\cdot a' < 2$ and so $E\subset 2^*$.

### Establish that $2^*\subset E$

This is the same argument from [Principles of Mathematical Analysis, Dedekind Cuts, Multiplicative Inverse](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175484/principles-of-mathematical-analysis-dedekind-cuts-multiplicative-inverse?noredirect=1&lq=1)) but modified to fit my narrative. I've also added some more (hopefully correct) exposition to justify the statements made.

Let's consider $p>0 \in 2^*$ since $p\leq 0 \in E$. Since $2-p>0$, $\exists n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\geq n$ and
$$ p < 2-\frac{2}{m+1} = \frac{2m}{m+1}$$ by the Archimedean property.

Let's consider positive $a\in A$ such that $0<a^2<2$ and $q$ such that $0<q<\frac{a}{n}$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Applying the Archimedean property twice, we can get
$$\begin{align*}
(mq)^2&<2\\
\big((m+1)q\big)^2&>2
\end{align*}$$
so that there is a "last" $m$ such that $mq\in A$ and $(m+1)q\not \in A$.

Then,
$$\bigg(\frac{p}{mq}\bigg)^2<\bigg(\frac{2m}{m+1}\cdot\frac{1}{mq}\bigg)^2=\frac{4}{(m+1)^2q^2} $$

Now since $(m+1)q \not\in A$, $\big((m+1)q\big)^2 > 2$ and so $$\frac{4}{(m+1)^2q^2} < \frac{4}{2} = 2\implies\frac{p}{mq} \in A$$

Then let $a=\frac{p}{mq}, a'=mq$ so that
$$a\cdot a' = \frac{p}{mq}\cdot mq = p \in E$$

So $2^*\subset E$.

### Show that $x\cdot x = 2 \implies \sqrt{2}\in\mathbb{R}$

Since $x=A|B$ is a Dedekind cut, we know that $x=\text{l.u.b }A$.

By the definition of Dedekind cut multiplication, we can safely say that for any two cuts $\alpha=W|X,\beta=Y|Z$,
$$\text{l.u.b }W \cdot \text{l.u.b }Y = \text{l.u.b }WY$$

Hence $(\text{l.u.b }A)^2  = \text{l.u.b } E \implies \text{l.u.b }A = \sqrt2$. So $\sqrt2 \in \mathbb{R}$.

---

> Questions:
>
> 1. Is this proof correct?
> 2. Is there a better way to do this?